# Trying to run a python script with a "portable python": ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, import

So I have a python script with command line arguments that works fine on my computer.
I run it from a bat like this:

```
Set PYTHONPATH=Folder1;Folder2
Set File=%~1

python %File% --arg1=value --arg2=value2
```

I want to deliver it to someone who does not have Python, I figured I would put the whole Python directory in the delivered archive.

Problem is, if I replace "python" in the above code by the path of the python.exe I put in the archive along with the rest of the required python files, it can't import the py files in Folder1 and Folder2. I guess the PYTHONPATH changes I do at the beginning of the bat file are ignored because if I print sys.path at the beginning of the script I'm trying to run, Folder1 and Folder2 are missing.

I don't think I can use pyinstaller because actually the py script I'm talking about is edited by the person who receives the archive through another tool that has nothing to do with Python. The py itself is an input to the bat file and requires several libraries that I can't load because there are in Folder1 and Folder2 which are not seen by the python exe in the archive. I can't make an exe out of the script file because it is supposed to be edited by the user.

I'm a beginner with Python, so I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what is going on (and also how to fix the import module problem).

Comment: You need pyinstaller. You can't just give them your python, you need the libraries as well as the paths to them. `pip install pyinstaller` then `pyinstaller --onefile <name of the main py file>`

Comment: Well I should have explain in more details my situation because I don't think I can do that, I will edit my post

Comment: put the editable parts in an external yaml file and load it. There's no scenarios where someone has to edit `code`. All editables go into external files.